# Selecting max within partition for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have a pandas dataframe. My goal is to select only those rows where column C has the largest value within group B. For example, when B is "one" the maximum value of C is 311, so I would like the row where C = 311 and B = "one."

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1., 
    'A' : pd.Categorical(["test1","test2","test3","test4"]),
    'B' : pd.Categorical(["one","one","two","two"]),
    'C' : np.array([311,42,31,41]),
    'D' : np.array([9,8,7,6])
    })

df2.groupby('C').max()
```

Output should be:

```
test1 one 311 9
test4 two 41  6
```

Comment: The question linked above was asked this morning (US Pacific time)

Comment: Applying `Paul H` solution to your problem yields: `df2.groupby('B').apply(lambda k : k[k['C'] == k['C'].max()])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `idxmax()`, which returns the indices of the max values:

```
maxes = df2.groupby('B')['C'].idxmax()
df2.loc[maxes]
```

Output:

```
Out[11]: 
       A    B    C  D
0  test1  one  311  9
3  test4  two   41  6
```